# Get A Google Doc Element By ID with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Question:
I am trying to avoid looping through the document until I find the tag and then grabbing the parent. Does anyone know if there is a way to find a google doc element by an id or handle?

Context:
I have a script that opens a defined template doc; copies it into a new document element by element, and then replaces any mustache tags with the values from a passed in object using the replaceText function. This part works fine, but there is one section where I would like to repeat a table row based on the object value being an array. Unfortunately I can not seem to figure out how to locate the table in the template doc other than something like:

```
if('{{ some tag }}' in aElement){
 var repeatableElement = aElement.getParent();
 if(repeatableElement){
   goRunRepeatFunction();
 }
}
```

Just seems like there should be a way to jump directly to an element by id.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output you expect?

Comment: The input would just be a google doc with various paragraphs, images, and tables in it. The goal is to grab one of those elements by a predefined name and manipulate it. something similar to jQuerys $('#idTag').someFunction();

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task can be accomplished by using this snippet:

```
function getElement() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var numOfElements = body.getNumChildren();
  var element = body.getChild(INDEX_OF_THE_CHILD).asText();
  console.log(element.getText());
}
```

This gathers the `body` of the document and retrieves the number of children it has. This number represents the elements the document has. So, in order to access a certain element, you just have to make use of the `getChild(index)` method

#### Note

Please bear in mind that the `getNumChildren()` method will end up returning the number of **all** the elements in the document, including empty lines - these will be considered elements as well.

Usually, when working with a document in Apps Script, the elements are retrieved by their types in order to preserve them. So for example, if you have `images` in your document, it'd be best to retrieve those by using the `getImages()` and this will end up returning a list of containing all the images in the document, with each image being accessible by their index.

Another method would be to retrieve all the paragraphs in the body by using the `getParagraphs()` method, but *if you know the exact structure of your document*, you can retrieve all the elements by their type, and then access them as such.

#### Reference

- [Class ContainerElement - getNumChildren()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#getNumChildren());
- [Class ContainerElement - getChild(Integer)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#getChild(Integer));
- [Class Body - getParagraphs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getparagraphs).

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. Do you know if there is a way to tag or id an element? So for example I have 8 tables in my template document and currently I do know the index, but ideally I would like to name one "someId" this way if I add a new table to my template I do not have to change my code.

Comment: Directly no, as the ids of the elements are set by default in the order they appear in the document. You can try using the [`findElement`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findelementelementtype) method and later use the result of this. Cheers!

Comment: If you have the element is there a way to get the index number that it is inside of the parent?

Comment: To retrieve the `index` directly of an element, the only method available is the [`getChildIndex()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild) one.